# Folders in Bing Maps

Tags: 2013, geolocation

I'm using Geolocation field on Sharepoint 2013 and it is working but I have the items in the list inside folders, so when I open the view nothing appears in the Bing map, I have to choose one folder and then the items on that folder are rendered in the map. What I need is to render all the items inside the folders in the same map.

Comment: OK, I'll ask the obvious question, is there any particular reason why you need to use the folders?  If the folders have e.g. country names, you could just create a new column called country and label each item with the country name. instead of using the folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can open up the view properties and enable the option to show items inside folders. This will show all items on the map irrespective of whether it resides inside a folder.

[image]

I would also suggest using metadata to drill down the map locations as opposed to folders.

Comment: That's true, good point.